# iPhone XCODE Programming make a UIWebView Scrollable

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

here is the problem! I have a UIWebView in my programs that loads a php page.
The problem is that if the page has a lot of lines i cannot see them.
I can "scroll" the UIWebView but when I leave the finger from the screen the page comes back to the original state.
I don't want to scale pages to fit the view cause if I do that the letters become too small.
I would like to find a way to scroll pages how it is possible in Safari.
Hope i have explained the problem.
Thank you in advance 
Antonio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control of the web page, it is easier to control the UIWebView with http than programmatically.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend applying the following:

1. Set `scalesPageToFit=YES` before the `UIWebView` gets loaded. I know you don't particularly want to scale the whole thing - but once you can scroll and zoom then having a macro view can be a good starting point.
2. Set the bounce behavior, within

   ```
   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {

       //turn multi touch on for theWebView!!!
       theWebView.multipleTouchEnabled   = YES;

       //control bounces and bounesZoom for the boundary
       [[theWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setBounces:YES];
       [[theWebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setBouncesZoom:NO];

       ....
   ```

These two things did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the scalesPageToFit-Property of the UIWebView.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit

Answer (score 0):

you can always use

```
UIWebView *wv = [controller webbrowser];
[wv loadHTMLString:pageUrlToLoad baseURL:nil];

wv.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

It does the trick for me.
it will try to fit the entire page in the window.

---

**ADD ON:**

write `UIWebView` in XCode window and pressing the ALT key, double click on it.

it will show the Fast Help window, there you can find projects using that View

- click on **`UI Catalog`** and when it opens, click the button **`Open with XCode`**
- select the folder you want to have all the project files and go
- select the iPhone Simulator 3.1.3 as the target device and Run the app.

You will get a lot of User Interfaces and all the code they use is right there so you can copy/paste and change to your own way.

give it a shoot!